# Create a wordlist using hashcat?

Tags: passwords, cracking, hashcat

Hashcat doesn't support the target application I'm trying to crack, but I'm wondering whether the mask function can be 'fed' the list of passwords and parsed through the rockyou rule to generate an effective wordlist for me?

If so, how can this be done as the documentation leaves lots to be desired.. !

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used HashCatRulesEngine:

https://github.com/llamasoft/HashcatRulesEngine

You can chain all the HashCat rules together, it then union selects them, weeds out any duplicates and takes as input your sample password file.

It then generates all possible permutations.

For instance:

```
echo "password">foo

./hcre /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/Incisive-leetspeak.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/InsidePro-HashManager.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/InsidePro-PasswordsPro.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/T0XlC-insert_00-99_1950-2050_toprules_0_F.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/T0XlC-insert_space_and_special_0_F.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/T0XlC-insert_top_100_passwords_1_G.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/T0XlC.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/T0XlCv1.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/best64.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/combinator.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/d3ad0ne.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/dive.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/generated.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/generated2.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/hybrid /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/leetspeak.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/oscommerce.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/rockyou-30000.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/specific.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/toggles1.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/toggles2.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/toggles3.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/toggles4.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/toggles5.rule /Users/chris/Downloads/hashcat-4.0.0/rules/unix-ninja-leetspeak.rule < foo >passwordsx
```

1 password the word "password" was permutated a total of:

```
bash-3.2# wc -l passwordsx
  227235 passwordsx
bash-3.2#
```

Times meaning that each word you feed into this generates 227235 possible combinations roughly giving you full coverage..

Answer (score 1):

You can use hashcat itself as a candidate generator by adding the --stdout switch (then pipe to your file or program of choice). I haven't tried all the possibilities, but it should work with any of the supported hashcat modes.

Here's an example using a ruleset: https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=rule_based_attack#debugging_rules